Nginx overwrites desired port when using proxy_pass on a subdirectory to direct request to node server
I have the following nginx config:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /home/tom/local.tjrhodes.com.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /home/tom/local.tjrhodes.com-key.pem;

    root /home/tom/Nextcloud/local.tjrhodes.com/webroot/;
    
    error_log /home/tom/Nextcloud/local.tjrhodes.com/logs/error.log;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name local.tjrhodes.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location /pat/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}

I call the /pat/ path with fetch on the client but the port 3000 on the proxy_pass command is overwritten with 443 as I'm testing locally over https. What am I missing in the config?
`
I've tried the node server calling it directly with the correct port (127.0.0.1:3000) and it responds ok. I can't make the request from the client when connecting over https though.

ssl on; - see https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl: "This directive was made obsolete in version 1.15.0 and was removed in version 1.25.1. The ssl parameter of the listen directive should be used instead."

"... but the port 3000 on the proxy_pass command is overwritten with 443 as I'm testing locally over https." -  So far this is only a claim without any indicators. And I doubt this claim. Please provide the steps how you exactly tested, what exactly happend and how you came to the conclusion that the parameter is overwritten.

Ok, for completeness here is the config that works for me...
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate /data/home/tom/local.tjrhodes.com+3.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /data/home/tom/local.tjrhodes.com+3-key.pem;
    
    server_name local.tjrhodes.com;
    
    root "/data/home/tom/Cloud/local.tjrhodes.com/webroot/";
    
    index index.html;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location ^~ /pat/   {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name local.tjrhodes.com;
    
    return 301 https://local.tjrhodes.com$request_uri;
}


change your nginx config to this:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /home/tom/local.tjrhodes.com.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /home/tom/local.tjrhodes.com-key.pem;

    root /home/tom/Nextcloud/local.tjrhodes.com/webroot/;

    error_log /home/tom/Nextcloud/local.tjrhodes.com/logs/error.log;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name local.tjrhodes.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /pat/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}


removed depricated on ssland added proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; to forward the original protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) of the client request to the backend server

Please don't just dump a new config. Instead explain what your change does and why it should fix the problem.

Don't graduate staging ground posts just so that you can answer them. Staging ground posts are meant to be reviewed, so please review them. It's hard to see how an Nginx configuration question can be considered on-topic for Stack Overflow.
